Test loss immediately goes up on LSTM
I'm trying to create an LSTM that predicts the sixth sports match for team A based on a sequence of 5 previous matches. My data is set up in a structure like this. Team A game 1 vs random team, team B game 1 vs random team, ... Team A game 5 vs random team, team B game 5 vs random team. Team B is the team that Team A is playing in the sixth game and the result is the output. Each sequence consists of 124 features which is the combination of both team A's i'th game and team B's i'th game.
My problem is is that my test loss immediately goes up, and I cant seem to be able to every have it decrease consistently. I've messed around with the hyperparameters, but none of them seem to have a noticeable effect. What can I do?
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch import nn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    # Device
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    print(torch.cuda.is_available())
    print(f'Running on device: {device}')

    # Process data
    data = pd.read_csv('matchup_data.csv')

    # Columns that are one-hot encoded for the label
    labels = data['label']

    # Remove the original one-hot encoded label columns from the features data
    data = data.drop('label', axis=1)

    # Convert features and labels to tensors
    dataT = torch.tensor(data.values).float()
    labelsT = torch.tensor(labels.values).float()
    labelsT = labelsT.unsqueeze(1)

    print(labelsT.shape)
    print(dataT.shape)

    # Split to test and train data
    train_data, test_data, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(dataT, labelsT, test_size=.1)

    # Layer parameters
    input_size = 124
    hidden_size = 64
    num_layers = 2
    output_size = 1
    sequence_len = 5

    # Net and net parameters
    net = LSTMnet(input_size, output_size, hidden_size, num_layers).to(device)
    print(net)
    loss_function = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.0001)

    train_accuracy, train_losses, test_accuracy, test_losses = trainModel(50, net, optimizer, loss_function,
                                                                          train_data, train_labels, test_data,
                                                                          test_labels, sequence_len, device)

    print(np.max(train_accuracy))
    print(np.min(train_losses))
    print(np.max(test_accuracy))
    print(np.min(test_losses))

    # Plot accuracy and loss
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.plot(train_accuracy, label='Train Accuracy')
    plt.plot(test_accuracy, label='Test Accuracy')
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
    plt.legend()

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.plot(train_losses, label='Train Loss')
    plt.plot(test_losses, label='Test Loss')
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('Loss')
    plt.legend()

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


class LSTMnet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size, num_hidden, num_layers):
        super().__init__()

        self.input_size = input_size
        self.num_hidden = num_hidden
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        # RNN layer
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, num_hidden, num_layers)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.6)

        # linear layer for output
        self.out = nn.Linear(num_hidden, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Run through RNN layer
        y, hidden = self.lstm(x)

        # pass through dropout
        y = self.dropout(y)
        # Pass to linear layer
        output = self.out(y)

        return output, hidden


def trainModel(num_epochs, net, optimizer, loss_function, train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels, sequence_length, device):
    # Variable initialization
    train_accuracy = np.zeros(num_epochs)
    train_losses = np.zeros(num_epochs)
    test_accuracy = np.zeros(num_epochs)
    test_losses = np.zeros(num_epochs)

    for epochi in range(num_epochs):
        net.train()

        segment_loss = []
        segment_accuracy = []
        for timei in range(len(train_data) - sequence_length):
            x = train_data[timei:timei + sequence_length]
            y = train_labels[timei:timei + sequence_length]
            x = x.view(sequence_length, -1, net.input_size).to(device)
            y = y.view(-1).float().to(device)
            output, hidden = net(x)
            output = output[-1]

            y = y.unsqueeze(1)
            loss = loss_function(output, y)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            # Convert output logits to probabilities using sigmoid
            probabilities = torch.sigmoid(output)
            # Convert probabilities to binary predictions
            predicted = (probabilities > 0.5).float()
            # Calculate accuracy
            acc = (predicted == y).float().mean() * 100

            segment_loss.append(loss.item())
            segment_accuracy.append(acc.item())

        train_losses[epochi] = np.mean(segment_loss)
        train_accuracy[epochi] = np.mean(segment_accuracy)

        net.eval()
        test_loss = []
        test_acc = []

        with torch.no_grad():
            for timei in range(len(test_data) - sequence_length):
                x = test_data[timei:timei + sequence_length]
                y = test_labels[timei:timei + sequence_length]

                x = x.view(sequence_length, -1, net.input_size).to(device)
                y = y.view(-1).float().to(device)

                output, hidden = net(x)
                output = output[-1]
                y = y.unsqueeze(1)
                loss = loss_function(output, y)

                # Convert output logits to probabilities using sigmoid
                probabilities = torch.sigmoid(output)
                # Convert probabilities to binary predictions
                predicted = (probabilities > 0.5).float()
                # Calculate accuracy
                acc = (predicted == y).float().mean() * 100

                test_loss.append(loss.item())
                test_acc.append(acc.item())

            test_losses[epochi] = np.mean(test_loss)
            test_accuracy[epochi] = np.mean(test_acc)

    return train_accuracy, train_losses, test_accuracy, test_losses


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Do you have a baseline model that does better? If other types of model are equally bad, it might simply be that your data does not contain any information that can be learned from. (Which in your case would imply that a team's form cannot predict their chance of winning? It does sound like that ought to be a good predictor.)
